# White screen after deploying react app with no error in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I had deployed my project on "c panel" with following steps.

1. Build project using "npm run build"
2. compress all files in build folder and past and extract them to "c panel".

When i am hitting url i am getting white screen.

As i have read lot of previous question so i tried few things but non of which worked for me.

i do not have any "homepage:'.' " in my package.json (i am not sure if it is required as i am not in subdomain).

dummy url: https://araffiliates.com

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
 
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
 
);

reportWebVitals();
```

app.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router basename="/">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
            <Route path="/*" element={<Dashboard />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

console has one error which i am sure is not causing this problem.
`[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED') (anonymous function) o (anonymous function) o (anonymous function) (anonymous function) (anonymous function) (anonymous function) Global Code`

Can someone please help me here.

I tried adding "homepage:'.'" in package.json
also tried few variation in 'basename' of routes but non of that worked.

Comment: Go to Network tab in dev tools and check if the requests for .css and .js are to the correct endpoints.

Comment: I just tried to load the url and it seems load just fine ;)

Comment: @DallogFheir both .css and .js file is "Referer" to  " https://dummyURL.com/ " url

Comment: @Chris, my bad correct url is "https://araffiliates.com" above mentioned url was dummy url just to protect actual url. editing same url into my question as well.